# Cointegration in ARIMAX regressions in R?

Tags: r, arima, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I’m running some ARIMA(X) regressions in R with several (control-) regressors including dummy variables and have some general questions concerning possibly cointegrated variables in ARIMA regressions.

I always thought, that cointegration is a phenomenon one can only control for in VECM. So I never checked if my variables are cointegrated, I simply checked for stationarity, took differences and ran the model. Now I just found a sentence in chapter 9.1 of the textbook by [Hyndman and Athanasopoulos](https://otexts.com/fpp2/estimation.html), that one could leave the variables undifferenced if they are cointegrated.

For that I have three questions:

1. Is it harmful for my ARIMA egressions that I differenced variables that might be cointegrated? Does this lead to somehow biased estimates?
2. How should one deal with cointegrated variables in an ARIMA setting? Is there a possibility to include an error correction term as in VECM ? I’m not aware of any argument/specification in R for that.
3. How should one deal with a model in which some variables are cointegrated (with $Y_t$ or with other regressors) and some are not (I include up to 10 different variables including some dummies, so I don’t expect them all to be cointegrated)?

Thank you so much in advance for any comments and help!
Kind regards
Stefan Schöncke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Unnecessary (excessive) differencing can inject structure

2) Identifiable contemporary and lag structure does  not require pre-differencing

3) one can mix and match the nature of the predictors.

https://autobox.com/pdfs/SARMAX.pdf